# Setting up a Timeline with a for loop in JavaFX

Tags: loops, animation, canvas, javafx, timeline

I'm trying to write an animated sort for a class I'm in.  My goal is to have the sort displayed as vertical white bars that will be rendered on the canvas I've created.

I've attempted to accomplish this using a **Timeline and Keyframes**, but the output I get is a blank white canvas that after a few moments outputs the finished and sorted array.

I've resorted to just shuffling around code with no success, and can't find any helpful examples online.  I'm hoping someone with some more experience with JavaFX animation can help me learn more about how to properly set this up!

Note that in the code below the array created with the random method is commented out because when used it makes the program hang for long time.  The code will output in a reasonable time with a smaller array.

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Project06 extends Application
{
    final int SCALE = 16;

    final int WIDTH = 64;
    final int HEIGHT = 32;

    int[][] pixels;

    Timeline sortLoop;

    int[] myArray = {32,28,22,20,16,13,10,9,5,3};


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        pixels = new int[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

        int[] myArray = new int[WIDTH];

        /*
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++)
        {
            myArray[i] = rand.nextInt((HEIGHT) + 1);
        }
        */

        Canvas display = new Canvas (WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE);

        GraphicsContext gc = display.getGraphicsContext2D();

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.add(display, 0, 0);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Sort");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(grid, WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));
        primaryStage.show();

        sortLoop = new Timeline();
        sortLoop.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

        // Sort array
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length - 1; i++)
        {        
            if (myArray[i] > myArray[i + 1])
            {
                int swap = myArray[i];
                myArray[i] = myArray[i + 1];
                myArray[i + 1] = swap;
                i = -1;
            }

            // Clear screen by zeroing out pixel array
            for (int k = 0; k < WIDTH; k++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++)
                {
                    pixels[k][j] = 0;
                }
            }

            // Draw array with vertical bars (assign values to canvas array)
            for (int k = 0; k < myArray.length; k++)
            {
                for (int j = (HEIGHT - 1); j > ((HEIGHT - myArray[k]) - 1); j--)
                {
                    pixels[k][j] = 1;   
                }
            }

            KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), actionEvent -> {

                // Render canvas
                for (int k = 0; k < WIDTH; k++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++)
                    {
                        if (pixels[k][j] == 1)
                        {
                            gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                            gc.fillRect((k*SCALE), (j*SCALE), SCALE, SCALE);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                            gc.fillRect((k*SCALE), (j*SCALE), SCALE, SCALE);
                        }
                    }
                }

            });

            sortLoop.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
            sortLoop.play();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: All your keyframes have the same timepoint, so they all happen at the same time. I'm not exactly sure what the code here does (just scanned it), but you probably want something like `Duration.seconds(i+1)` for the time points for the key frames. Still not sure that will work, as (I think) all the modifications to the array will have happened by the time the animation occurs.

Comment: `Duration.seconds(i+1)` does make the finished sorted image appear faster (the blank white canvas that had appeared for a few moments before the array appears is gone).  It also makes sense that if the modifications to the array had finished by the time the animation occurs that it wouldn't be visible, however, I had hoped that since I placed the `KeyFrame` and the `sortLoop.play();` calls inside of the loop that runs the sort, each time it made a pass through the loop it would update the animation.

Comment: So you should modify the array in the key frame's event handler, not elsewhere.

Comment: I've tried that as well, it was my initial approach to writing my code.  Unfortunately it doesn't make a real difference.  I can get an still output of an unsorted array or a sorted array, but not an animation of an array being sorted.  Now I'm just shuffling around code trying to get a different output.  At this point my approach seems to have devolved to the efficiency of a bogosort, and I'm hoping to get some input as to if this is sensible approach to begin with, or if there is another way that might be more reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are setting the timepoint for all your key frames to the same value (one second), so they all happen simultaneously. You need each key frame to have a different timepoint, so they happen sequentially.

Second, you sort the array, and then the event handlers for the keyframes reference the array. Since the event handlers for the keyframes are executed later, they only see the sorted array. You need to actually manipulate the array in the event handlers for the key frames.

Third, you play the timeline multiple times. You only need to play it once. Additionally, you set the cycle count to `INDEFINITE`: I think you only need to animate the sort once. (If you actually want it to repeat, you would need to set the array back to its original order at the beginning of the timeline.)

Finally, you have some issues in the implementation of the actual sort algorithm. This is why your application hangs when you randomly populate the array. I won't address those issues here, because the question is about how to perform the animation.

The following code performs a step-by-step animation. It's probably not the correctly-implemented sort, so you won't see the animation you necessarily expect, but it at least repaints the effect of the swaps in an animation:

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class AnimatedSort extends Application
{
    final int SCALE = 16;

    final int WIDTH = 64;
    final int HEIGHT = 32;

    int[][] pixels;

    Timeline sortLoop;

    int[] myArray = {32,28,22,20,16,13,10,9,5,3};


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        pixels = new int[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

//        int[] myArray = new int[WIDTH];
//
//        
//        Random rand = new Random();
//        for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++)
//        {
//            myArray[i] = rand.nextInt((HEIGHT) + 1);
//        }


        Canvas display = new Canvas (WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE);

        GraphicsContext gc = display.getGraphicsContext2D();

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.add(display, 0, 0);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Sort");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(grid, WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));
        primaryStage.show();

        sortLoop = new Timeline();
//        sortLoop.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

        // Sort array
        for (int index = 0; index < myArray.length - 1; index++)
        {        

            final int i = index ;

            KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(i+1), actionEvent -> {

                if (myArray[i] > myArray[i + 1])
                {
                    int swap = myArray[i];
                    myArray[i] = myArray[i + 1];
                    myArray[i + 1] = swap;
//                    i = -1;
                }

                // Clear screen by zeroing out pixel array
                for (int k = 0; k < WIDTH; k++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++)
                    {
                        pixels[k][j] = 0;
                    }
                }

                // Draw array with vertical bars (assign values to canvas array)
                for (int k = 0; k < myArray.length; k++)
                {
                    for (int j = (HEIGHT - 1); j > ((HEIGHT - myArray[k]) - 1); j--)
                    {
                        pixels[k][j] = 1;   
                    }
                }

                // Render canvas
                for (int k = 0; k < WIDTH; k++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++)
                    {
                        if (pixels[k][j] == 1)
                        {
                            gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                            gc.fillRect((k*SCALE), (j*SCALE), SCALE, SCALE);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                            gc.fillRect((k*SCALE), (j*SCALE), SCALE, SCALE);
                        }
                    }
                }

            });

            sortLoop.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
        }

        sortLoop.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this!  There is definitely more going on with KeyFrames than I'd realized.  I understand now that you have to keep track of the frames that are generated, as well as the amount of frames that will be needed to process the entire sort.  I am now able to work out a (poorly implemented) way to display the full animation that I was trying to create.  This has saved me hours of digging around and I think it has pushed me over the hump of understanding how KeyFrames work.  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The `time` property of `KeyFrame` denotes the time since the start of the animation, not the time since the previously added `KeyFrame`. You need to position. You need to pass different times to the `KeyFrame` constructor.

Furthermore you "sort" a fresh array instead of using the field. Also your `pixels` array contains the last value from the start.

Better save the swaps to a data structure and use a `Timeline` to render the changes step by step:

```
final int SCALE = 16;

final int WIDTH = 64;
final int HEIGHT = 32;

Timeline sortLoop;

int[] myArray = {32, 28, 22, 20, 16, 13, 10, 9, 5, 3};

private void renderBar(GraphicsContext gc, int barIndex, double canvasHeight, int barHeight) {
    double rectHeight = barHeight * SCALE;
    gc.fillRect(SCALE * barIndex, canvasHeight - rectHeight, SCALE, rectHeight);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    int[] myArray = this.myArray.clone(); // copy field (you may also simply delete this declaration, if you never reuse the initial array)

    class Swap {

        final int lowerIndex, value1, value2;

        public Swap(int lowerIndex, int value1, int value2) {
            this.lowerIndex = lowerIndex;
            this.value1 = value1;
            this.value2 = value2;
        }

    }

    final double canvasHeight = HEIGHT * SCALE;
    Canvas display = new Canvas(WIDTH * SCALE, canvasHeight);
    GraphicsContext gc = display.getGraphicsContext2D();

    primaryStage.setTitle("Sort");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(display)));
    primaryStage.show();

    // render initial state
    gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    gc.fillRect(0, 0, display.getWidth(), canvasHeight);
    gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        renderBar(gc, i, canvasHeight, myArray[i]);
    }

    // Sort array & save changes
    List<Swap> swaps = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length - 1; i++) {
        if (myArray[i] > myArray[i + 1]) {
            int swap = myArray[i];
            myArray[i] = myArray[i + 1];
            myArray[i + 1] = swap;
            swaps.add(new Swap(i, myArray[i], swap));
            i = -1;
        } else {
            // no change
            swaps.add(null);
        }
    }

    sortLoop = new Timeline();
    sortLoop.setCycleCount(swaps.size());
    final Iterator<Swap> iter = swaps.iterator();
    sortLoop.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), evt -> {
        Swap swap = iter.next();

        if (swap != null) {
            // clear old area
            gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            gc.fillRect(SCALE * swap.lowerIndex, 0, SCALE * 2, canvasHeight);

            // draw new bars
            gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            renderBar(gc, swap.lowerIndex, canvasHeight, swap.value1);
            renderBar(gc, swap.lowerIndex+1, canvasHeight, swap.value2);
        }
    }));

    sortLoop.play();
}
```